# Iterate over a C++ container in C

Tags: c++, c, iterator, containers, stdmap

I am attempting to write a C wrapper for some C++ data structures. Right now I've got the following in `foo.cpp`

```
typedef std::map<unsigned int, void *> _Map;

extern "C"{
    void* map_create()
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<void*> (new _Map);
    }

    void map_put(void *map, unsigned int k, void *v)
    {
        Map *m = reinterpret_cast<_Map *> (map);
        m->insert(std::pair<unsigned int, void *>(k, v));
    }
}
```

In `foo.h` I've got

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif
typedef void *Map;
EXTERNC void *map_create();
EXTERNC void map_put(void* map, unsigned int k, int v);
```

I include `foo.h` and I'm good to go.

Now, I wanted to iterate over a map and noticed C++ does that through iterators. I have no experience with C++ and don't know how iterators are implemented.

Can I iterate over a `std::map` using a C wrapper? How would these functions definitions look like and how would I use them in a for-loop in my C code?

Comment: 1) Avoid starting your identifiers with underscore characters. --  2) *...and don't know how iterators are implemented.* -- You're not supposed to.  An [iterator is a concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator), not an exact type.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - you give up pretty easy.

Comment: @CrazyEddie There's no portable solution through casting I know of.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sometimes understanding how something is implemented can help you solve problems. know  it's a concept but I thought it might help in this case

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Start an API like this:  `void *getIter( void *map );` returns a pointer to some C++ construct that holds the necessary iterator.  void *getNextValue( void *iter ); gets some pointer to a C++ construct that can be used to get the next value.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Who said anything about casting? Just as you can wrap the creation and the instertion into a function, you can do the same for the iterator increment, decrement, dereference ... functions. It's just going to be pretty ugly.

Comment: @MikeMB Probably no more ugly than the set of C `stdio.h` functions `fopen()`, `fread()`, etc., but definitely tedious.

Comment: @lsund The problem is not "how", it is that a `map:::iterator` can be implemented in any way the compiler implementor sees fit, as long as it meets the requirements of the concept.  Even a `std::map` can be implemented in various ways, as long as it meets the requirements of a `std::map`.

Comment: @lsund: The question you should ask yourself first is *"How do you want to use those functions in a for loop / what should the interface look like"* And from that we can talk about a suitable impelmentation or tell you, that it won't work like this and you e.g. need an aditional parameter

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can't you use a *pointer* to an iterator and cast that to `void*` to pass back into C? I don't see why that's so impossible.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I actually don't have a problem with those (they don't look much different than the member functions on an fstream), but for the naive approach you'd have to write at least 6 different functions that all take (or return) a void star parameter (begin,end, increment, comparison, de-referencing, delete) with the additional level of indirection because you have to create them on the heap.

Comment: @MikeMB I did say it'd be tedious... :-)

Comment: *Aside*: [`std::make_pair()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) exists. In the original post, one could avoid repeating the template arguments, like so: write `m->insert(std::make_pair(k, v));`

Comment: Unrelated to the question: your use of `reinterpret_cast` is actually inappropriate: using the implicit conversion to `void*` from a typed pointer is just fine. This standard conversion can be safely undone using a `static_cast`. The key constraint is that the target type of the `static_cast` is the same type which was used in the original conversion.

Comment: I think you got the entire question backward. Just as you are not supposed to write C in C++, you are also not supposed to write C++ in C. Provide an interface which is idiomatic in C (I don't the idiomatic way to represent a map in C, but I'm sure you can do some research on that), and then *implement* the interface with iterators on the C++ side. From a C point of view, the C++ map's iterators should be considered an implementation detail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to use iterators directly. You *can*, of course, do something along the lines of creating/releasing objects and obtain the values somehow. It isn't going to be efficient, though. It would look something like this:

```
typedef std::map<unsigned int, void*> map_type;
typedef map_type::iterator            map_iterator;

void* map_iterator_create(void* map) {
    return new map_iterator(map.begin());
}
void  map_iterator_destroy(void* it) {
    delete static_cast<map_iterator*>(it);
}
int map_iterator_next(void* map, void* it, unsigned int* key, void** value) {
    map_iterator* mit = static_cast<map_iterator*>(it);
    if (static_cast<map_type*>(map)->end() == *mit) {
        return 0; // no more elements
    }

    *key   = mit->first;
    *value = mit->second;
    ++mit;
    return 1;
}
```

This particular approach does reduce the flexibility coming with iterators a bit (e.g., it doesn't support subranges) but these could be supported at different costs. You'd use this iterator approach like this:

```
void*        it = map_iterator_create(map);
unsigned int key;
void*        value;
while (map_iterator_next(map, it, &key, &value)) {
    printf("key=%d value=%p\n", key, value);
}
map_iterator_destory(it);
```

It is probably more reasonable to not expose the iterator interface but rather an interface iterating over the sequence, e.g.:

```
extern "C" { typedef void (*map_function)(unsigned int, void*, void*); }
void map_iterate(void* map, map_function fun, void* userdata) {
    map_type* m = static_cast<map_type*>(m);
    std::for_each(m->begin(), m->end(),
                  [=](map_type::value_type const& v) {
                      fun(v.first, v.second, userdata);
                  });
}
```

... which would be used as

```
void my_iterating_fun(unsigned int key, void* value, void* userdata) {
     printf("key=%d value=%p\n", key, value);
}
// ...
map_iterator(map, my_iterating_fun, 0);
```

I haven't tried to compile the code (i.e., it is probably riddled with small typos) but something along those lines should work.

Comment: GRRR - and I was so close to hitting submit with an answer so similar.

Comment: @UKMonkey: that seems to be OK - yours may be slightly different, providing a similar, yet, probably somewhat different alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that won't compile, but gives you an idea on how I'd do it

```
class MyIterator {
  public:
    MyIterator(Map map) {
      it = map.begin();
    }

    void advance() {
      ++it;
    }

    bool isValid() {
      return it != map.end();
    }
  private:
    Map::const_iterator it;
    const Map map;
};

extern "C" {
void* newIterator(void* map) {
  return new MyIterator(static_cast<Map>(map));
}
void freeIterator(void* it) {
  delete static_cast<Map>(map);
}
void advanceIterator(void* it) {
  static_cast<MyIterator>(it)->advance();
}
void isValid(void* it) {
  static_cast<MyIterator>(it)->isValid();
}

int getKey(void* iterator) {...}
void* getValue(void* iterator) {...}
}
```

Comment: it, indeed, is along a similar idea but also quite different. The primary reason I'm exposing a different interface is that the function calls to the different iterator accessors are bound to become somewhat expensive when the functions can't be inlined. Hence, I folded the test, value extraction, and advance into one function. This seems to be the typical approach when using dynamic polymorphic iterators as is, e.g., the case in Java and C#.

Comment: indeed - as I already posted in my response! BTW, I didn't downvote your answer. I'd be interested in the reason for the downvote, though.

Comment: I guess it largely depends on what one plans to do - if you want to iterate over everything, or if you want to be able to stop iterating

Comment: the approach to an early exit could be a corresponding return from the called function, of course.

Comment: I imagine the reason for the down vote is that it gives the API user a chance to create a memory leak.  That said, it's not an uncommon concept for a C interface to have a 'create' & 'destroy' function, and they'll be very used to it

Comment: The API is indeed somewhat ugly, but that is to be expected. Imho the real problem is the catastrophic code that obscures more than it explains. And it doesn't even show how to use the interface to iterator over the map, which was the actual question.